# Git branch not working the way I expected it to

Tags: git

In my project *master* branch I commit changes: `git commit -a`

create & switch to new branch: `git checkout -b newbranch`

try some stuff...

realize 'stuff' didn't work out the way I thought it might so switch back to master: `git checkout master` with intent of moving along from there... but realize some files added in newbranch are still in TextMate... so...

I type `git status` I still see all the stuff I thought I'd left in newbranch is listed under "Untracked files"

I try: `git reset --hard` to take me back to that last commit..but changes in newbranch still persist?!?

what am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What are you missing? Well, the files in questions are untracked and git wouldn't touch those with a ten-foot pole. ;)

In all honestly, if you weren't going to commit anything there was probably no reason to checkout a new branch.

You could have tried the new changes as normal. If you didn't like what you saw but wanted to use the new code later, you could have stashed it, like so:

```
git stash save "Some changes that didn't work out."
```

If you absolutely wanted it gone instead, all you had to do was:

```
git clean -d --dry-run
```

and then when sure:

```
git clean -df
```

Comment: by default you need to add the f modifier as I mention in my answer.

Comment: I like this workflow. I think I'll use it in the future. thanks!

Comment: `-n` is a synonym for `--dry-run`

Answer (score 1):

If certain files are untracked, then git won't do anything to those files.

Comment: ah... so, in theory. i should have committed those in newbranch? and then when I switched back to master they'd be removed...and i could then delete the newbranch?

Comment: or, is there a way to remove all *untracked* files?

Comment: Removing untracked files is done with `git clean`. Useful options: -n (pretend) -f (force), -d (dirs), -X (only ignored) -x (ignored as well)

Comment: If you were on the newbranch, you could commit all files (`git add .` I think, but I'm not certain). That way you wouldn't have any untracked files. But I don't know if you can just delete untracked files without using plain old `rm`.

Comment: clean by default requires the force option. If you do this a lot, consider changing your config to not require clean being forced.

Answer (score 1):

since you have untracked files (I'm assuming you did not commit them) you have a dirty working directory. If you want to zap those as well, you can use the clean command:

```
git clean -df
```

The d modifier specifies that you would like to act upon untracked directories as well. The f modifier specifies force. Clean will not remove things if you don't specify this parameter by default. You could add the x modifier in case you would want to delete ignored files as well, but I would not recommend that.

Comment: `clean -X` is super useful, it has replaced `make clean` for me.

Comment: this really depends what you are programming in. The -X is an absolute no-no for my workflow in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

From the symptoms described it seems that you may have untracked files. Untracked files will remain when switching branches.

To clear untracked files

```
git clean -dfx
```

To reset changed files to the head of the branch you are currently on

```
git reset --hard
```