# Changes (erroneously) reflected in multiple branches

Tags: git

- I'm in the master branch.
- I create a new branch with `git checkout -b new_feature`, and am now in `new_feature`.
- I do some file changes in `new_feature`.
- I switch back to `master` with `git checkout master`.
- The exact changes made in `new_feature` are now in `master` as well, without me merging the branches.

What is going here? Any idea why I no longer can do isolated changes in a branch, without them being reflected in other branches?

Comment: The changes are not there, only your working directory.  Commit your work first before switching branches.

Comment: When you think a tool is working "erroneously" take a moment to consider whether you just don't understand the tool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git branch not working the way I expected it to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339738/git-branch-not-working-the-way-i-expected-it-to)

Comment: @Chris Of course I could have put the title "(Because I'm stupid) changes are reflected in multiple branches". It never crossed my mind that Git does something wrong here, rather my intended outcome was not as expected - thus "erroneous".

Comment: `It never crossed my mind that Git does something wrong here` ... it isn't doing anything wrong.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry for my vague english, that's exactly what I tried to say. I did not think there was an error with Git. The erroneous behaviour was 100 % on my part.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I think the OP is acknowledging that.

Comment: I agree that it's weird that Git allows you to switch branches while your working directory is dirty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you switch branches, the uncommitted changes will be reflected in the new branch.

In order to isolate your changes in the `new_feature` branch use [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing) or commit your changes before switching your branch to `master`.